# Removing relevance data from Marklogic query results

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

With the below query I would like to modify the options so that I am only retrieving the values.  The query returns the path, the relevance as well as values.  I just need the values so I can edit it for reporting purposes.  Can I get some insight on how to accomplish this task?  I am also using the Javascript API within Marklogic 8.

```
results = jsearch.documentSelect(cts.search($error_details), 
                     {namespaces: {//emf:namespace is declared here},
                      extract: {paths: ['//emf:properties/emf:property[@key = "filename"]/.',
                               '//emf:properties/emf:property[@key = "idnumber"]/.',
                               '//emf:properties/emf:property[@key = "error description"]/.',
                               '//emf:properties/emf:property[@key = "error code"]/.']}
                     }).toString();
```

The query

```
cts.andQuery([
cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName('uri','creation-time'), ">=", $startDate),
cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName('uri','creation-time'), "<", $endDate),
cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName('uri','component-name'), "InvalidFiles" ),
cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName('uri','category'), "error")
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the jsearch.documentSelect() wrapper might not be necessary in this case.

The cts.search() function returns the documents as a ValueIterator in MarkLogic 8.

One easy way to process the documents is to chain the toArray() functions -- as in cts.search().toArray() -- and then chain the standard array map() or reduce() functions to convert the documents into the report.

Footnote:  cts.search() returns a Sequence in MarkLogic 9, but sequences also have a toArray() function.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks.  I didn't realize that I could run queries without jsearch when using the Javascript API

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple [search options](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#chapter) which allow you to customize your search response. For example, you can disable to return aggregates with this option:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <return-aggregates>false</return-aggregates>
</options>
```

> The query returns the path, the relevance as well as values.

If you mean score, confidence and fitness by "relevance", i dont think there is an option for that.